# UIButton not performing action from function in a different class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a class where written is a function creating my button:

LoginButton.swift

```
func createButton() {
    let myButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Foo().buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }()
}
```

Now in my second class, Foo.swift, I have a function that just prints a statement

Foo.swift

```
@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button was pressed")
}
```

When ran I get no errors except when I try to press the button, nothing happens. Nothing prints, the `UIButton` doesn't react in any way. Really not sure where the error occurs because Xcode isn't printing out any type of error or warning message.

Comment: Are you sure the button you are pressing is the same button as `myButton`?

Comment: @Sweeper I only have one button on my screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing with target. So make instant of target globally and make use of it as target for button action handler.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let foo = Foo()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createButton()
}

func createButton() {
    let myButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitle("Tap me", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self.foo, action: #selector(self.foo.buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    myButton.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(myButton)
}
}
```

Class Foo:

```
class Foo {

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button was pressed")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for `Foo` to extend `NSObject`.

Comment: Yes no need of `NSObject`, Removed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The action method is called in the target object. Thus, you have either to move `buttonPressed` to the class which contains `createButton` or to pass an instance of `Foo` as a target object.

But note that a button is not the owner of its targets. So, if you just write:

```
button.addTarget(Foo(), action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

This will not work, because the `Foo` object is immediately released after that line. You must have a strong reference (e.g. a property) to `Foo()` like

```
let foo = Foo()

func createButton() {
    let myButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(foo, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just pass `Selector` as function argument.

```
func createButtonWith(selector: Selector) {


    let myButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: selector), for: .touchUpInside)

    }()

}
```

And call this function like below...

```
createButtonWith(selector: #selector(Foo().buttonPressed(_:)))
```

Comment: The problem is that the function from the second class won't execute. I don't need to pass it as an argument, that's of no use in this case.